# Cut custom shape from transparent layer of image css

Tags: css

What i am trying to achieve is [image: custom shape cut from tranparent layer of image]

I am able to achieve this by following code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
div{
    position:relative;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:175px; top:25px;
    border-radius:100%;
    width:150px; height:150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
body{background: url('http://cdn.home-designing.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/living-room.jpg');background-size:cover;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But what if we want some complex shape polygon which cannot be represented alone by either circle, rectangle but by mixture of these shapes.

Comment: If your polygon is something that can be created with CSS then use the same approach. If not, use SVG.

Comment: This is obviously done with svg. Try researching svg clippath.

Comment: It's basically a logo which can be created by mixture of rectangles and circles using css .

Comment: Please show what shape you are trying to achieve. otherwise it will be hard to suggest any approach to make it.